# Im getting an error in the one of the last lines "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

I keep getting an error saying that it cannot find the symbol, and I have looked but I don't know where it went wrong. It is going to print an array with the numbers that the user inputs and then from there find out what the max number is that they entered.

```
class Soutar_maximumvalue{

  public static void main (String[] args){
    //Welcome
    System.out.println ("Welcome to Matthew's program to find the maximum number.");

    max();

    //Goodbye
    System.out.println ("Thank you for using my program.");
   }

  public static void max(){
   //Variable Declaration
  double userinput1, userinput2, userinput3, userinput4, userinput5;
  double [] max;
   Scanner First = new Scanner(System.in);
   //Input
   System.out.println ("Please enter your first number.");
   userinput1 = First.nextDouble();
   System.out.println ("Please enter your second number.");
   userinput2 = First.nextDouble();
   System.out.println ("Please enter your third number.");
   userinput3 = First.nextDouble();
   System.out.println ("Please enter your fourth number.");
   userinput4 = First.nextDouble();
   System.out.println ("Please enter your fifth number.");
   userinput5 = First.nextDouble();

   max = new double [5];
   max[0] = userinput1;
   max[1] = userinput2;
   max[2] = userinput3;
   max[3] = userinput4;
   max[4] = userinput5;
   System.out.println( Arrays.toString( max ) );

   System.out.println (Math.max(userinput1,userinput2,userinput3,userinput4,userinput5));  // This is the line with the error
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really look like javascript...

Comment: You should post the printed error, the line number, and your Java version.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.max` isn't variadic in java. It takes two arguments

A solution would be to replace

```
Math.max(userinput1,userinput2,userinput3,userinput4,userinput5)
```

with

```
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(max))
```

thanks to the array you just created.

Comment: it says no suitable methods found for max